# Problems with sinusoidal curve fitting: amplitude and frequency come out too low

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

[image: data]

I have some time series data, which corresponds to the black line in the image (it's a rolling mean). I am trying to fit a sinusoidal curve to it with no success; the light blue, almost straight line is the current result. (The dark blue one is a polynomial fit, disregard it for now).

What I tried is this. I got the idea for the function from [here.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/curve-fitting-with-python/)

```
def objective(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.sin(b - x) + c * x**2 + d
```

[..]

```
from scipy import optimize

X = X.ravel() # 1D array of ordinal dates
y = y.ravel() # 1D array of temperature values

# Curvefit with the objective function.
params, _ = optimize.curve_fit(objective, X, y)

# Plot the curvefit
plt.plot(X_extended, objective(
    X, params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]))
```

Even if I add guesses with very low frequencies or very high amplitudes, barely anything changes.

Any idea is appreciated. If necessary, I can try to reproduce the issue elsewhere.

---

Applying the p0 values and function that were given in the answer, the graph now looks like this:

[image: newly fitted function]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without data to test, it's hard to tell exactly. However, a good guess is that your starting parameters are off, and then a generalised least squares fit can (easily) fail. You're not even giving `curve_fit` an initial set of parameters, so the initial starting of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` will all be set to 1.

Dealing with *only* the sinusoidal fit, for your amplitude `a`, you'll probably want something around 7, and for the offset `d`, about 27. `b` is harder to guess, so can be left at 0 (or 1) initially.

But, the quadratic part of the equation will make a mess of things: the x-values are large, so it will change very fast, or rather, `c` should be very close to zero (close, as in very small, of order `1/x^2`, so say `~ 1e-12`, to cancel out the effects of the large quadratic variations. Any such small number will have problems fitting as well: normalising your formula / parameters (to be of order 1) beforehand is always a good idea.

In fact, I don't understand why you have a quadratic in your function. Perhaps it's the underlying model that requires this, but the figure itself shows no indication at all of quadratic behaviour. I would remove it.

Finally, while you have an x-offset `b`, you don't have a parameter for your the period. As a result, it will be fixed at 2π, which it is definitely not. This will be the biggest hurdle in fitting your data, next to the quadratic part of the equation. The period looks to be around 300 (or one year?), or roughly 50 * 2π.

So, try with the following function:

```
def objective(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.sin(b - c*x/50) + d
```

with starting parameters of, very roughly:

```
p0 = [7, 0, 1, 27]
```

and see what you get.

(If you are wondering about the 50 in the formula: it's not really necessary at these orders of magnitude, but it servers as an example of normalising `c` to be of order 1. You could so the same for `d` by replacing it with `10*d` and then set its initial guess at 3. Or, if you do that, you can now leave out `p0` entirely, with all parameter guesses at 1.)

Comment: That works extremely well, and your post was very insightful to me! Check the edit in the question for a plot of your suggestion, if you're interested. I used you values verbatim, and they fit very well.

Comment: Indeed. Is it yearly behaviour? And is that montly behaviour on top of that? Almost tempting to fit another sine on top of it with a shorter period. That really requires good initial guesses, because otherwise you just end up with two sine fits for the larger curve, each accounting for half of it.

Comment: It is yearly behavior. I do not believe there is much monthly behavior to be found, and if it was, it is not that relevant to my goal. I am trying to find a date in the future where a certain positive temperature threshold is violated. I believe the function now does not show trends, correct? That would be something I require, since I expect a gradual warming. (Edit: I added a linear component. Will have to evaluate. Thanks for the help, again!)

Comment: If you're talking about (world) climate temperature behaviour, not something indoor or on another planet, then any gradual warming will not be seen over a period of just one year. Climate scientists tend to use a rolling mean over a 30-year window to see changes (using a mean yearly temperature, thus ignoring yearly variations), so you should look at those timescales.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is about battery temperatures that have a life span of about 10 years. The temperature threshold is not always violated before capacity or charge cycle EOL is reached, but it may happen. And some show a very linear trend in warming overall, it's just that this particular type is also very vulnerable to the seasons, it seems :)

Comment: Ha, quite different then. Well, if the battery is not shielded (much) from the weather, then I could imagine it will follow that trend as well. Or simply that the thermometer picks up too much environment.